# Set connection name with amqplib

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I need to set a friendly name for my connection as below instead of "?" in RabbitMQ for amqplib for NodeJS:

[image]

I found examples with Java and Python but nothing yet with this library.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can set the connection name by passing it in the client properties:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', {clientProperties: {connection_name: "myFriendlyName"}})
```

[image]

For reference:

https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/217