# NestJS RabbitMQ set connection name

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

How do I set rabbitMQ connection name so it displays on management console using NestJS?. I don't see any option for that in RmqOptions interface.

I want to set friendly name for the connection like in this post:
[Set connection name with amqplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650010/set-connection-name-with-amqplib)

I've dome research on web. Reffered to NestJS docs and looked into code.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
      {
        transport: Transport.RMQ,
        options: {
          queue: this.queueName,
          urls: [this.host],
          prefetchCount: 1,
          headers: {
            ['state']: 'initial',
          },
          noAck: false,
          noAssert: true,
          persistent: true,
          queueOptions: {
            durable: false,
            messageTtl: 700,
          } as AmqplibQueueOptions,
          socketOptions: {
            clientProperties: {
              connection_name: '<NAME_YOUR_CONNECTION_HERE>',
            },
          } as AmqpConnectionManagerSocketOptions,
        },
      },
      { inheritAppConfig: true },
    )
```